# Wallposts and comments

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I've made one table for all comments on a social network site: comment

Also, I've one table for all comments assigned to one comment: comment_assign

So, I built a function comment() to implent it easily in each section type (images, userpage, groups, etc). In case of $_GET['s']==user, I want to have wallposts as well as comments on these wallposts. All stored in 'comment'.

I've got this scheme to display this: 
1. sql query to get the comments
2. html output
3. another sql query inside this html output to get specified assigned comments of a comment (wallpost in this case)

Now the problem is that my first query displays all comments. Also comments that are supposed to be subcomments. So my question is, if there's any way to specify in this first query, when I get all my comments, to say: Look in comment_assign if this comment_id is available. And if it is, don't display this comment, because it's a subcomment (that I'll display in mentioned step 3).

Maybe this whole structure may be changed? I would appreciate any suggestions. Even hard to realized ones, but which would be the most efficient.

---

Table structure:

**comment**

id, uid, nid, site, text, date

**comment_assign**

comment_id, assign_id

---

First SQL Query example, which doesnt work to avoid displaying all the comments (also assigned ones). See the last line:

```
SELECT *    
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `comment_assign` AS ca ON ca.`comment_id` = c.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON c.`uid` = u.`id` 

WHERE c.`nid`='".$nid."' 
AND c.`site`='".$_GET['s']."' 
AND ca.`comment_id` != c.`id`
```

Comment: If I edit my last line to: "AND ca.`comment_id` IS NULL" it works. But still the structure with these two queries are not very efficient, regarding to output all the data fast and programming efficient, I guess? Should I somehow change my table_structure or bundle these two queries into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you select all the comments from the **comment** table. You then want to check to see if comment.id is present in comment_assign.comment_id. If it is present, it is a sub-comment. Is that correct?

You can do it two ways - the clean way is to add another field to the **comment** table and put assign_id there, since each comment can only be associated with another comment, or is a top-level comment (*assign_id is NULL*).

Alternatively, you could LEFT JOIN both tables. Every row where assign_id is NULL, is a wall comment, every row where it has a value means it is assigned as a sub-comment. i.e.

```
SELECT id, uid, site, text, date
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN comment_assign ON (comment.id = comment_assign.comment_id)
WHERE comment_assign.assign_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you post. I've just commented my question above with the same solution. I read that if there aren't that many cases where a table row won't be filled with data, you should make another table. That's why I didn't add a table row named assign_id to table 'comment'. So, now I'm confused, because you said that this would be the clean way. Do you know what I mean? Also, like in my comment of my question at the top: Do you think I should somehow change my table structure or bundle these two queries to one?

Comment: Because later I'll have another while-loop and SQL-Query to display these subcomments, also with a SQL join.

Comment: To me it makes sense to add the field to the original table. Most likely, you'll have more sub-comments than comments eventually, so it won't be that empty. But you will save a lookup.

If you want to save querying the database and process more in your code, you can SELECT all the comments, sorting them by *assign_id* and then parse the array in order. i.e. loop through the results, output the original comment, then when assign_id is NOT NULL, output the record as a sub-comment.